# Ace editor - different color for class and function name

Tags: ace-editor

In ACE editor tool[code panel], am trying to set different color for CLASS NAME AND FUNCTION NAME, but all the words in the code have been gets identified as literal, so in that case if i set color entire code is getting set to the specified color. How can i include custom color only for class and function name.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a highlighter that assigns different types to class names and function names. For which language are you trying to do  this?

Comment: For python.. Can u help me by providing the information about the creation?